# "Relative cell complexes in the undercategory $B/\mathscr{M}$ are relative cell complexes in $\mathscr{M}$": why do we need $B$ to be a cell complex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathscr{M}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}$The context: the following is claimed in J. May's "more concise algebraic topology".

We have some model category $\M$ which is generated by arrow classes $\I,\J$. For any $B\in\M$, the undercategory $B/\M$ has a model structure generated by the classes $B/\I,B/\J$ which are defined to be the classes of all arrows in the image $((-)\sqcup B)(\I,\J)$ respectively. Here, $(-)\sqcup B:\M\to B/\M$ is the left adjoint to the forgetful $U:B/\M\to\M$.

May wants to demonstrate that when $\M$ is compactly or cofibrantly generated, then so is $B/\M$. To do so, he claims that, **when $B$ is an $\I,\J$-cell complex**, then relative $B/\I,B/\J$-cell complexes in $B/\M$ descend (via $U$) to relative $\I,\J$-cell complexes in $\M$.

I don't see why the assumption that $B$ is a cell complex is needed.

---

First of all, by some set theoretic shenanigans I can take all my relative cell complexes to be simple. I also only need to show the result for, say, $\J$. A $B/\J$-relative cell complex will look like some transfinite sequence $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ where $X_{\alpha+1}$ is obtained from $X_\alpha$ as a pushout (in $B/\M$) of some $C\sqcup B\overset{j\sqcup1}{\longleftarrow}A\sqcup B\to X_\alpha$ (again, a diagram in $B/\M$) where $j:A\to C$ is an arrow in $\J$. This pushout may as well be computed in $\M$, however; although colimits in an undercategory are not generally computed as they might be in $\M$, pushouts are, and I am sure that transfinite compositions are too.

So I now only consider the sequence $(X_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ in $\M$. It's easy to check $A\hookrightarrow A\sqcup B\to C\sqcup B,\,A\to C\hookrightarrow C\sqcup B$ defines a pushout square. We can compose pushout squares to find a pushout square $A\to X_{\alpha}\to X_{\alpha+1},A\to C\to X_{\alpha+1}$. Since the left leg of this square is an arrow in $\J$, continuing in this way finds $X_\ast$ as a $\J$-relative cell complex. The "middle man" $B$ can be omitted entirely.

Am I mistaken, or is May?

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632820)

Comment: I’ve answered at the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4632820) on math.stackexchange.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a duplicate of a question on math.SE, now answered there.  To be clear, I think cross-posting here was fine according to [our general guidelines](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3457/if-i-cant-get-an-answer-on-math-stackexchange-com-or-dsp-stackexchange-com-whe), but now that it’s answered there, assuming OP is satisfied, it shouldn’t remain open here as well.